# AXIOS Request does not send data to PHP server

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, axios

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, GET, POST");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");

print_r(file_get_contents('php://input'));
```

This is my PHP server page to handle a request from a react.js client on localhost:3000

this is the code of the client

```
let handleSubmitDesign = (event) => {
event.preventDefault();
let url = 'https://www.myserver.com/test.php'; //Server example
let data = {
  key: k,
  code: code,
  role: role,
  cat: 1
};
sendPostRequest(data, url, fun);
```

}

This is the first function

```
function sendPostRequest(data, url, fun) {
let newData = JSON.stringify(data);
axios.post(url, newData)
.then(function (response) {
  //console.log(response.data);
  fun(response.data);
})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

}

Of course the data are not empty and i can check using a log , if a use a third party API tool test as https://reqbin.com/ i can check my server page works fine , same thing with a React Native mobile app, but not for this React.js app

the print_r funcion , or an echo function let me see i don't recive anything

Comment: https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/axios/post-json: _"If you happen to have a serialized JSON string that you want to send as JSON, be careful. If you pass a string to axios.post(), Axios treats that as a form-encoded request body."_

Comment: @CBroe i tryied to add to my server header('Content-Type: application/json'); did you meant this ?

Comment: No, I didn't. That would be a response header. I meant exactly what the example on the page I referred you to shows.

Comment: @CBroe so i could remove let newData = JSON.stringify(data); to let axios handle the data ?

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. I filled in the missing variables, and the value passed to `fun` (which I had to define) was the data I input in the first place.

Comment: @Quentin fun is just a function which set the value of the response in a variabile of the state (remember I'm using react js), so doesen t matter what it does, if I console.log the response of the server I can see that it never receive the data from the client, I repeat , with other client it works! and I don't know why this time no.

Comment: @Naigel — I console.logged the data and **did** receive it.

Comment: @Quentin with the same code I wrote here ?

Comment: As much as possible, as I said there were some gaps I had to fill (like undefined variables).

Comment: @Quentin which undefined variables ? if you mean fun it's just a function who set a value with the value you pass it, doesn't matter what it does to solve the problem

Comment: `fun`, `k`, `code`, `role`, & `event`

Comment: @Quentin lol, why you need to know what value they are ?? the problem is the server doesen't get a value in the input from the request, these value could be "1", "2", "3" etc.. and the server should response with a JSON with all of these data, and about "fun" already answer, Of course the event was a click of a button, but anyway this thing doesn't matter

Comment: " lol, why you need to know what value they are ??" — I never said I did. I said I had to fill them in in order to test the code. If I don't then I get a reference error.

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass also headers.

```
function sendPostRequest(data, url, fun) {
let newData = JSON.stringify(data);

const headers = {
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
  //Authorization: token, Bearer token or whatever applies
}

axios.post(url, newData, { headers:headers })
.then(function (response) {
  //console.log(response.data);
  fun(response.data);
})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: I'll try it soon